# mysql load_file all prereqs fulfilled but still not working

Tags: mysql, binary, blob

I got an issue with MYSQL LOAD_FILE. Whenever I execute sth like 
`UPDATE product_category SET thumbnail= LOAD_FILE('C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads\thumbnail.png') WHERE id = 2;`

I get

> 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

so bascially nothing happens and LOAD_FILE returns null

MYSQL Manual says the funtion comes with following preconditons

- the file must be located on the server host -> **done**
- you must specify the full path name to the file -> **done**
- you must have the FILE privilege -> **done** (If I run `SELECT user, file_priv FROM mysql.user`; I get a Y for my user)
- The file must be readable by all -> **done** (I granted everybody full access to the file and the whole folder)
- its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes. -> **done** (its size is 63KB and max_allowed_packet=1073741824)
- if the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory. -> **done** (I choose the directly exactly this way)

Anybody an idea what's wrong? Or any idea where I can find some helpful error messages or how to enable them?

cheers
tom

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to load the file into separate table and from that table you can update records accordingly

Comment: Thanks. Can you let me know into what table I need to insert it? I found other posts mentioning select load_file(...); but that also did not return anything but null

Comment: You have to create table w.r.t the file and its column.

Comment: I tried the following but without success. CAn you please tell me what exactly is needed or where I can find the related info. The manual doesn't seem to give any decent info unfortunately. Thanks again!  `create table fileup(
 pic blob
);

UPDATE fileup
SET pic= LOAD_FILE("C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads\samsung.png");`

Comment: Tell me the columns of your file

Comment: my table goes like this and thumbnail is the column for the image. thanks again! `create table if not exists product_category (
 id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 label varchar(64) not null, 
 parent int null,
 thumbnail blob null,
 active boolean not null,
 FOREIGN KEY fk_parent (parent) REFERENCES product_category (id)
);`

Comment: Just doesn't work tried like on http://www.knowledgewalls.com/johnpeter/books/one-day-one-thing-to-know/how-to-insert-blob-in-mysql-using-loadfile-method but as before the load_file always returns null inspite of all prereqs fullfilled as far as the manual goes.